# How to register Nuget packages in Blazor_Server_Side?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have added InstagramApiSharp nuget package to the Blazor_server_Side.

When I write:

```
services.AddInstagramApiSharp();
```

In configuring service method in the startup page, A red line appears under it. Why?
Should I add a singleton or inject it?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're likely injecting it perfectly fine, but there can be a number of reasons you're seeing the error in the UI. Generally mousing over it and reading the mouseover text will indicate what's wrong, but here are a few suggestions of what might cause that:

- Failing to include the appropriate using statement at the top of your class indicating where the extension method can be sourced. In Visual Studio, you might be able to hit Ctrl + Space with your cursor on the offending text to get an auto-fix suggestion that may add this for you.
- If you do have the necessary using statement, it may also be that you require one or more arguments to be passed to the method.
- This may not be a method available in the package. You don't indicate where this is coming from, but I'm guessing it's from [here](https://github.com/ramtinak/InstagramApiSharp), and a quick pass through the documentation doesn't indicate that this is at all how it's intended to be used. I strongly suggest looking through some of the samples provided (with the caveat that it's noted that this library (v1.5.0.2) available on NuGet is no longer maintained in the readme).

Answer (score 0):

I first added these namespaces to my code:

```
@using InstagramApiSharp.API;
@using InstagramApiSharp.Classes.Models;
@using InstagramApiSharp.API.Builder;
```

Second added Class name to User name and password:

```
var userSession = new UserSessionData
        {
            UserName = Enterance.username,
            Password = Enterance.password
        };
```

And the problem is solved!